# if $S=\left\{ x \in Q | x^2 < 2\right\}$ Prove $S$ has an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I claim that it is true because our professor believes so, and here is my proof, 
 Suppose there is a number $x'> 2$ such that $x'^2 > 4$ however $x'^2 < 2$ therefore contradiction and hence $x$ has an upperbound.
I have a feeling it is wrong, can someone explain to me why.

Comment: It has an upper bound because $77$ is an upper bound. The square of any rational $\gt 77$is greater than $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The germ of your argument is correct but the words you are connecting the statements with are fogging it up.  Let me read this as a grader would:

> Suppose there is a number $x′>2$ such that $x′^2>4$

OK, no problem there.  *Any* number $x'>2$ will satisfy $x'^2>4$.

> however $x′^2<2$

Wait, why?  Are you also assuming $x' \in S$?  Now we really have a problem because no $x' \in S$ has $x^2> 4$.  Or is this what you were trying to prove?

> therefore contradiction and hence x has an upperbound.

**What is the upper bound?**

Let's try that again.  What is the definition of *upper bound*?

> > Let $S$ be a set of real numbers.  The number $M$ is an *upper bound* of $S$ if $x \leq M$ for all $x \in S$.

To show $M$ has an upper bound, the easiest way is to name a number $M$ and show $x \leq M$ for all $x$ in $M$.

It looks like you want to say that $2$ is an upper bound.  So say it, and prove it:

> We claim $2$ is an upper bound of $S$.  To show this, suppose $x \in S$.  Then $x^2 < 2$.  If $x < 0$, then $x < 2$ already.  If $x > 0$, then $x^2 < 2 \implies x < \sqrt{2}$.  Since $\sqrt{2} < 2$, we know $x < 2$.  Therefore $2$ is an upper bound of $S$.

In general, to show $X$ is a $Y$, look up the definition of $Y$ and show that $X$ satisfies it!

Comment: Thank you! I understand where I went wrong and everything. Very clear!

Answer (score 2):

The number $2$ is an upper bound for $S$.  Take $x \in S$. If $x \leq 1$ then $x < 2$. If $x > 1$, we use that $x  < x^2 < 2$. That is, $x <2$ for **any** $x \in S$.

Comment: but if x= 1/2 then x^2= 1/4 so x^2 < x

Comment: Look again.. I broke it into cases. If $x \leq 1$ you do not need to use the condition $x^2 < 2$. My objective is to prove that $$x \in S \implies x < 2,$$whatever it takes.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! Is my proof wrong though

Comment: The contradiction you're trying to get isn't making much sense to me. The logical would be something like:

"Suppose that $S$ does not have an upper bound. Then, given any $M > 0$, exists $x \in S$ such that $x > M$. Choose $M = 4$, for example. But $x \in S \implies x^2 < 2 \implies x < 2 < 4$, a contradiction."